# lsp function doesn't work

Tags: lsp-mode

I installed lsp-mode and using pyright as its server. However, most of the lsp function wouldn't work. For example, If I do M-x lsp-find-definition, it'll return error message "Symbol's value as variable is void: xref-auto-jump-to-first-definition".

Does anyone have this issue before? I've re-install my lsp-mode a couple of times but it wouldn't work.

Comment: Of coarse, Emacs version is important, but also did you installed the package ```lsp-pyright```?

Comment: @lan, Yes, I think I did. I have use-package lsp-pyright in my config file and in the Message buffer it also says pyright is initialized in the folder. I couldn't find lsp-pyright in the M-x though.

Comment: May depend on your configuration - try ```M-x lsp``` to start lsp server working, or add a hook to your configuration: ```(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'lsp-deferred)``` to start automatically.

Comment: My lsp-mode starts automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
xref-auto-jump-to-first-definition is a variable defined in ‘xref.el’.
  ...
  This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
  version 28.1 of Emacs.
```

Are you using Emacs 27 or earlier?

I can see an upstream bug report for this at https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/4063 which indicates that if you install a newer xref from GNU ELPA (as opposed to the version included as standard in Emacs 27) then this problem might go away.

(If you subsequently upgrade to a more-recent version of Emacs you might want to revert back to the in-built xref.)

Comment: Yes, I am using Emacs 27, which probably causes this issue. But is there any way to use lsp-mode functions within Emacs 27?

Comment: I couldn't even find the 'xref.el'. Is it in the ~/.emacs/elpa folder? @phils

Comment: Xref is part of Emacs since 25.1.  `M-x find-library`

Comment: I can see that lsp-mode means to support 27.1 and higher, so raise a bug report with them so that they can add some backwards compatibility for this issue.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that I could find xref from M-x. Not sure if I can revise the codes to solve this issue.

Comment: https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/4063 indicates that if you install a *newer* xref from GNU ELPA this problem might go away.  (If you subsequently upgrade to a later version of Emacs you might want to revert back to the in-built xref.)

Comment: I couldn't even install xref in emacs. It doesn't exist in M-x package install or M-x package reinstall.

Comment: I can use xref to go to definition or find references. But it's much less convenient than directly using lsp-mode.

Comment: `M-x package-refresh-contents` then `M-x package-list-packages` then `/ n xref` to filter by name (no "filter by upgradeable" command in 27.1), then `i x` against the `xref` entry to install it.  (You can't `M-x package-install` it because a version of that package is *already* installed, and you can't `M-x package-reinstall` it because that's for things which you had manually installed in the first place, whereas xref is a standard part of Emacs (which happens to additionally be available in ELPA).

Comment: This works! Finally! Thanks so much!